# Setting innerHTML of elements with the same ID

Tags: javascript

In my body I have 3 `<a>`s with the same IDs and different colors (red, green and blue) to identify them.

```
<a id="hello" style="color: Red;">[Blank]</a>
<a id="hello" style="color: Green;">[Blank]</a>
<a id="hello" style="color: Blue;">[Blank]</a>
```

And in my script I have this:

```
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Hello world!";
```

As a result, only the first `<a>` (with a color of red) will appears as "Hello world!" [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/axDEL/2/).

I change my script to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Hello world!";
}
```

The result remains the same, with only the first `<a>` (with a color of red) appearing as "Hello world!".

Suppose I want all 3 `<a>`s appearing as "Hello world!". How do I do that?

Comment: You can't have three elements with the same ID. An ID must be **unique** within a document. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: "elements with the same ID" These shouldn't exist! It's what classes are for.

Comment: Was just wondering :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what classes are for, IDs are unique.

Replace every `getElementById` in your code with `getElementsByClassName` and you're good to go.

HTML

```
<a class="hello" style="color: Red;">[Blank]</a>
<a class="hello" style="color: Green;">[Blank]</a>
<a class="hello" style="color: Blue;">[Blank]</a>
```

JS

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].innerHTML = "Hello world!";
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5uy7B/

Comment: as a note: qsa has better support than getByClassName.

Answer (score 2):

javascript optimizes getElementById on the assumption that ids are unique. So it always only retrieves one element.

Use, instead, `.getElementsByClassName()`, and apply a common classname to each of the 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

From w3schools:

> The getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id.

IDs must be unique document-wide, so for your purpose you should use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead, which returns an array of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array. It returns a very different beast called a live node list (that actually changes as the DOM changes automagically). Also, getElementByID's behavior is unspecified for non-unique IDs. http://www.w3fools.com